# How can I use a Horizontal GridLayout inside a Recylerview adapter

Tags: android, gridview, horizontal-scrolling

I have `Recyclerview` in my layout. I am showing images inside the row Layout of this `recyclerview`. I am using Gallery widget for now to show the images.
But it is not giving me the desired results. I want to use `GridView` to show images. I want images to scroll horizontally in this `gridview` when there are more images than the width of device.
Please suggest me how can I achieve this.

Comment: Show your effort too.

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview great tutorial to use with everything. The layout manager would be what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview great tutorial to use with everything. The layout manager would be what you need :)